# SQL: select N “most recent” rows in ascending order

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

For example, if my data look like this:

```
timestamp | message
100 | hello
101 | world
102 | foo
103 | bar
104 | baz
```

How can I select the three most recent rows — 102, 103, 104 — in ascending order?

The obvious (to me) `… LIMIT 3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC` will return the correct rows but the order is incorrect.

Comment: You asked for the rows in descending order in the title, and _ascending_ order in the question, which are you looking for?

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. I want ascending. Fixed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an inner select to select the correct rows, and an outer select to order them correctly:

```
SELECT timestamp, message
FROM
(
     SELECT *
     FROM your_table
     ORDER BY timestamp DESC
     LIMIT 3 
) T1
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: Hrm… I don't have a running instance of postgres handy to try that with, but SQLite's `EXPLAIN` suggests that will result in a sort (two if the column isn't indexed). Is there any way this redundant sort can be avoided?

Comment: No; SQL does not have a "reverse" operation. But maybe the language into which you are pulling the results does?